# Redirected to server with nginx, how to serve files with original domain name

Tags: nginx

Not too sure on how to phrase the question. I have two servers, server A and server B.

What I want to achieve is that usa.serverA.com is serving files from server B, but it retains the domain name from server A.

Server A has been configured (using apache) to redirect usa.serverA.com to the server B's ip Address.

On server B, I have a wordpress site that is set up at usa.serverB.com with the following config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name usa.serverA.com;
    root /srv/www/usa.serverB.com/public_html;
  }
```

Currently,when a user types in usa.serverA.com, they get redirected to usa.serverB.com, which is great, but I want the domain name to remain at usa.serverA.com

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to serve the sub domain directly from server B, set server Bs IP address for usa.servera.com in your DNS.

Do you want to use server A as a proxy for server B? So that the requests for B always go through A? Then you could activate `mod_proxy` and put the following into your apache vhost config:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://usa.servera.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://usa.servera.com/"
```

Also add usa.servera.com with server Bs IP address to `/etc/hosts`.

([Apache Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html))